# How do I do a groupby in python to split between orders?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that shows order listing. How do I use it to find the number of orders that contain spicy food?

```
   Order       Item Name Spicy
0   1000  Calamari Rings    No
1   1001      Cheesecake    No
2   1001   Spicy Chicken    Yes
3   1002      Spicy Lamb    Yes
```

Using this code gives me 2 Yes and 2 No, but it should actually be 2 Yes and 1 No as order 1001 is duplicated. Thank you.

```
dd = df_orders.groupby("Item Name")["Order"].count()
```

I would like to get an output that shows the number of orders that contains spicy food.

```
   Spicy        
0    Yes   2
1     No   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's perhaps a simpler way, but this works.

First group by order and spicy counts, to get the count of spicy for each order.  Then sort by spicy and drop duplicates by order number (removes the 'No' in spicy column if a yes exists for that order). Then group by Spicy again and count to get the counts.

```
df_orders = pd.DataFrame({'Order' : [1000, 1001, 1001, 1002],
                          'Item Name' : ['Calamari Rings', 'Cheesecake', 'Spicy Chicken', 'Spicy Lamb'],
                          'Spicy' : ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes']})

df_grouped = df_orders.groupby(['Order', 'Spicy']).count().reset_index()
df_grouped = df_grouped.sort_values(by='Spicy').drop_duplicates(subset='Order', keep='last')
df_grouped = df_grouped.groupby('Spicy').count()['Order'].reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Spicy  Order
0    No      1
1   Yes      2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sort_values` to separate 'No' and 'Yes' spicy values then `drop_duplicates` before `value_counts`:

```
>>> df.sort_values('Spicy') \
      .drop_duplicates('Order', keep='last') \
      .value_counts('Spicy')

Spicy
Yes    2
No     1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue with this though is that the second item for Order 1001 is "Spicy", and by dropping the duplicated it will give the wrong output.

Comment: Please. can you update your post with your expect output, please?

Comment: Yes I've updated it. Thank you!

Comment: I think this is the outcome you expect?

Comment: Yes thank you! That's a great idea to drop duplicates as the solution. It works too :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure about how your output will look. You can try to sort according to `spicy` column such that `yes` comes first, then drop duplicates and count, this ensures you retain the yes:

```
df_orders = pd.DataFrame({'Order':[1000,1001,1001,1002],
'Item Name':['Calamari Rings','Cheesecake','Spicy Chicken','Spicy Lamb'],
'Spicy':['No','No','Yes','Yes']})

df_orders.sort_values("Spicy",ascending=False).drop_duplicates('Order')['Spicy'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Yes    2
No     1
Name: Spicy, dtype: int64
```

Comment: That's a very smart solution! Thank you. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

first groupby base on Spicy and then convert to a dict and with a loop on dict keys to access numbers of order that contains spicy food:

```
    dictionary = df_orders.groupby('Spicy')['Order].apply(list).to_dict()
    for k in dictionary:
       print(k, ':',len(dictionary[k]))
```